# @JsonValue on an enum field, when this enum used as map key

Tags: java, enums, jackson

```
public enum ClusterType {
    TEMPERATURE("0402"),
    HUMIDITY("0405"),
    ENERGY_DETAILS("0702"),
    SMART_SOCKET_STATUS("0006"),
    ALARMED("0500");

    private String value = null;

    ClusterType(String byteStr) {
        this.value = byteStr;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static ClusterType fromValue(final String val){
        return (ClusterType) CollectionUtils.find(Arrays.asList(ClusterType.values()), new Predicate() {
            public boolean evaluate(Object object) {
                ClusterType candidate = (ClusterType) object;
                return StringUtils.equals(candidate.value, val);
            }
        });
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    public byte[] get() {
        return ByteUtils.hexStringToByteArray(value);
    }

    public boolean equals(String cluster) {
        return StringUtils.equals(cluster, value);
    }
}
```

I have the above enumeration with

> @JsonValue
>       public String getValue(){
>           return value;
>       }

part and a sample test class like...

> public class Foo {
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     try {
>         ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
>
>         ClusterType []arrayRep = new ClusterType[]{ClusterType.ALARMED, ClusterType.TEMPERATURE};
>
>         Map<String, ClusterType>  mapRepAsValue = new HashMap<>();
>         mapRepAsValue.put("1", ClusterType.ALARMED);
>         mapRepAsValue.put("2", ClusterType.TEMPERATURE);
>
>         Map<ClusterType, String>  mapRepAsKey = new HashMap<>();
>         mapRepAsKey.put(ClusterType.ALARMED, "1");
>         mapRepAsKey.put(ClusterType.TEMPERATURE, "2");
>
>         System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(arrayRep));
>         System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mapRepAsValue));
>         System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mapRepAsKey));
>
>     } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> } }
> ```

This test class prints out

```
["0500","0402"]
{"2":"0402","1":"0500"}
{"TEMPERATURE":"2","ALARMED":"1"}
```

@JsonValue is not working when used on an enum field which is a key of map.

Is there a way to use this enum as key when serializing maps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jackson uses a `MapSerializer` to serialize `Map` types and uses a `StdKeySerializer` to serialize the keys. It's implemented as

```
@Override
public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
    throws IOException, JsonGenerationException
{
    if (value instanceof Date) {
        provider.defaultSerializeDateKey((Date) value, jgen);
    } else {
        jgen.writeFieldName(value.toString());
    }
}
```

which you can see just gets the `toString()` value of your object. So you can override the `toString()` method in your `enum` as such

```
public String toString() {
    return getValue();
}
```

The `@JsonValue` becomes useless.

Alternatively, if you need the `toString()` to remain the same (or default), you can create a custom type that wraps your `Map`

```
class CustomType {
    private Map<ClusterType, String> map;

    @JsonAnyGetter // necessary to unwrap the Map to the root object, see here: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-765
    @JsonSerialize(keyUsing = ClusterTypeKeySerializer.class)
    public Map<ClusterType, String> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<ClusterType, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```

and uses a custom `JsonSerializer`

```
class ClusterTypeKeySerializer extends StdSerializer<ClusterType> {

    protected ClusterTypeKeySerializer() {
        super(ClusterType.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(ClusterType value, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonGenerationException {
        jgen.writeFieldName(value.getValue());
    }

}
```

that uses the `ClusterType#getValue()` method. Again, we don't use `@JsonValue`.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I think this is just a feature that hasn't been added, as per:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/47

so whereas `@JsonValue` works fine for Enums with respect to deserialization, it does not yet work for serialization. Project is always open for contributions, if anyone has time to tackle this -- it should not be big undertaking.